# How to make qmail to feed email into shell command?

Tags: email

I have some server running qmail, with many users/domains configured via plesk. I would like to get emails from specified address delivered to one of my users being feed to shell command, as addition to normal delivery. So, basically, I have some shell script, and I'd like qmail to invoke my script with the email, and the continued with delivery as usual.

If necessary, I can do recipient/sender filterind on script side, though it could be more efficient and cleaner, if qmail would feed only correct emails to my script.

Anyway, how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dot-qmail](http://www.ezmlm.org/man/man5/dot-qmail.5.html) files.  Literally, you would just prefix the first line with a `|` and run it through a command.  The second line would specify the user to deliver the mail to.

For example:

```
|/usr/bin/procmail
&user1
```

This would pipe all e-Mail through procmail and then deliver to the local system user `user1`.